# i am getting this error when using list based views.no such table: first_app_theprofessionalresources

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

I am getting this error Exception Type: OperationalError Exception Value:no such table: first_app_theprofessionalresources

```
when i am trying to use list views in django,classbased views.
 TEMPLATE:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

{%for p in resource_list%}

{{p.Field}}
{%endfor%}

  </body>
</html>


VIEWS.PY
class TheProfessionalResourcesListViewCBV(ListView):
      context_object_name='resource_list'
      model=models.TheProfessionalResources

MODELS.PY
class TheProfessionalResources(models.Model):
    Field=models.CharField(max_length =100)
    Author=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ShortDesription=models.TextField(max_length=200)
    URL=models.URLField()
    type=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    SelfEmailAddress=models.EmailField(max_length=50)

    def __str_(self):
        return self.name

URL.PY
urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^basic_skeleton/',views.basic_skeleton,name='basic_skeleton'),
       url(r'^first_app/',include('first_app.url')),
       url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),

         

url(r'^Professional_Development/',views.Professional_Development,name='Professional_Development'),
        url(r'^Personal_Development/',views.Personal_Development,name='Personal_Development'),
        url(r'^Financial_Development/',views.Financial_Development,name='Financial_Development'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

second url.py
urlpatterns=[
url(r'^$',views.basic_skeleton,name='basic_skeleton'),
url(r'^Personal_Development/$',views.Personal_Development,name='Personal_Development'),
url(r'^Financial_Development/$',views.Financial_Development,name='Financial_Development'),
url(r'^Professional_Development/$',views.TheProfessionalResourcesListViewCBV.as_view(),name='Professional_Development'),
url(r'^Resources_Professional/$',views.Resources_Professional,name='Resources_Professional'),

url(r'^TheProfessionalResourcesCBV_list/',views.TheProfessionalResourcesListViewCBV.as_view(),name='list')
]
```

please help i have nowhere mentioned that particular table first_app_theprofessionalresources why is it showing me that?I just want to list the fields form the mode and then view theier details in a separate page.PLease help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just forgot to migrate your database, try

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/)

Comment: how many question can i post on stack overflow in a day? any ide?

Comment: just from reading your code i can guess a few more questions you will need answered, you should try to google or read the documentation first :)

Comment: thanks am doing that,figured out many bugs like that this one was hard for me iam cofing in django fir first time thanks taek i was really stuck at this.

Comment: Welcome to the django community then, if you have time you should consider doing the tutorial it's well written and will help greatly with all the basics.